# CRM 2011 - Javascript Button - Change field on all Entitie Records

Tags: javascript, button, dynamics-crm-2011, workbench

I have little experience with javascript and I am trying to select multiple entities and change the field from true to false and vice versa.
I tried to see the example of JS on the SDK but found nothing that i can understand, someone can help me with an example?

Update:
I do not think I could explain. So here goes, when I´m in a View, i need a button to change a particular field in all records, without having to select the record i can do it through a workflow using the [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx).

So far i can change via XRM the value but is only if i got the form open of that record.

```
  function test() 
{
var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
field = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_onoff").getValue();
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_onoff").setValue("offviaJava");
alert(id + field);
}
```

The aim is to do the same for every record in the VIEW

Comment: Hi, You want alter records values in one entity or for different entities?

Comment: In the same entitie, but diferrent records

Comment: See my update with another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For change multiple records for the same entity or for more than one entity the best way is using Workflow or Plugins. But my vote goes to Workflow is very easy make this type of changes. Check [here](http://info.profad.com/bid/63154/Creating-Workflows-in-Microsoft-Dynamics-CRM-2011) a example.

EDIT: Based in your update i suggest another option:

```xml
<Actions>
  <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:AccountFormLibrar" FunctionName="CreateNewAccount">
  <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControlSelectedItemIds"/></JavaScriptFunction>
</Actions>
```

```js
function CreateNewAccount (SelectedRecordGUID) {
 //the parameter will receive all GUIDS in comma separated
}
```

You have to add ribbon button and add a action.

Comment: Thnaks Pedro, ok now I can have all the guids, but how do I do an update of records using javascript only, no xml, soap etc?

Comment: Hi, See this [article](http://www.mscrmconsultant.com/2012/07/create-update-delete-record-using.html) that show how update a record with Soap.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of seeing data in Dynamics CRM, the grid view (where you see many instances at once) and the entity form view (where you see data for one instance in the current open window or tab). Using javascript to change the data, appearance and other actions on a form view is easily done, however it sounds like you are looking at a grid view since you mention multiple selections.

I do not think you should be doing javascript, but instead look at dialogs and workflows. A workflow is an asynchronous operation that runs in the background without any user input. It can do a lot out of the box, and you can add custom .NET-code to change the behavior as well. Dialogs are similar but collects user information as inputs to its actions (useful if user needs to make a choice or input something that change over time).

You can run a workflow manually by selecting one or more rows and clicking the workflow button. Similar process for a dialog.

More info: [Processes, Workflows, and Dialogs for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309471.aspx)

Comment: Hi Henrik, i can do it with resource of a workflow, what i'm trying to do is via javascript in GRID the dont need to select any record from that entatie and press the button and it changes the contents of a particular field

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved my problem as follows, since i could not restrict myself to the 50 records that the page gives in the view by using  `SelectedControlSelectedAllItemIds` , because the xml fetch only 50 guids on total.
So now the button calls a JAVASCRIPT URL of the ASP page and this was the code in c#:

```
 EntityCollection retrieved = GetInformacaoDB(new_teste.EntityLogicalName.ToString());

                    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("List");
                    dt.Clear();
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));

                    foreach (var c in retrieved.Entities)
                    {    
                            GridView1.Visible = false;                             
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                            dr["Description"] = c.Attributes["new_testid"];

                             object _test = c.Attributes["new_testid"];

                               string testGuid = _test.ToString();

                                Guid _testId = new Guid(testGuid);

                                Entity EntityName = new EntityName("new_test");

                                ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "new_testid" });

                                EntityName = _orgService.Retrieve(EntityName.LogicalName, _testId, attributes);

                                entidade["new_onoff"] = "OffViaWebService";

                                _orgService.Update(EntityName); 

                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                    }
                    ds1.Tables.Add(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    Cache["Data"] = ds1;
```